# Where do i save gunicorn_start.bash file

Tags: linux, django, bash, virtualenv, gunicorn

I am trying to setup gunicorn using django postgresql and ngingx

what directory should this file go to? "**gunicorn_start.bash**", inside of the virtualenv bin directory or in the root bin folder?

i am following this tutorial

http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is in the `virtualenv`, you need to save it there as well.